# How can i show left zeros?

Tags: php

How do I show the leading zeros of a field returned from mysql? For example: in a given field, I have the value "000A46" and I need to display the 3 zeros on the screen. However, PHP hides them. Shows only "A46".

Ps. "000A46" was just an example. It could be "000A4658" or "00000000S" and so on...

Comment: PHP won't remove the leading zeroes from a string unless you're doing something else to it like `number_format`. Can you show us the actual code involved, and the data type of the field in MySQL?

Comment: @ceejayoz is right, PHP won't trim leading 0's from string. Can you please tell us your column type? Better add some code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to this:

```
$val = "A46";
$val = str_pad ( $val , 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT );
```

Comment: Thank you Pablo. But "000A46" was just an example. It could be "0A4658" or "00000S".

Comment: @JetroBernardo This code works fine for that (with the one small adjustment I added to have it left-pad instead of right-pad).

Comment: $var = 000046; 
echo str_pad ($var , 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); // this shows "000038"

Comment: Hello @JetroBernardo! I understood the first time that "A46" was just an example. Likewise, the code I showed you was just an example. You need to replace `$val = "A46"` with whatever you get from your MySQL query...

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz for pointing this out!

Comment: @JetroBernardo `$var = 000046;` means you've got octals (base 8 instead of base 10) in play. That's going to mess **everything** up. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php "To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero)." MySQL shouldn't be giving you octal values; it should be giving you *strings*. `$var = '000046';` will work fine.